# Getting a login error to SQL Server, for a login I'm not using

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

We have a dev SQL Server which we connect our MVC apps to with just pass-through credentials in the EDMX file. When we are ready to test using credentials, we have a generic dev login, but I have searched my entire app, and it is not in there.

It has been working fine on my box, but today I put the app on our dev web server, and on the page that gets data from the dev SQL Server, I get a

> Cannot open database "MyApp" requested by the login. The login failed.
>   Login failed for user 'Domain\GenericDevLogin'.

So even though my app is set up to use pass through, somewhere it is hitting this login. Where should I look?

Edit to add connection string:

```
<add name="MyAppEntities" 
     connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.ApplicationData.csdl|res://*/Models.ApplicationData.ssdl|res://*/Models.ApplicationData.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=devSqlServer;initial catalog=MyDatabase;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;application name=EntityFramework&quot;" 
     providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Comment: Show us the **connection strings** - the one you use on your local dev machine, and the one you use on the dev web server

Comment: Ok, see edit on main ,

Comment: your connection string is having - integrated security=True, that means, it tries to login into SQL server using windows credentials. You either may need to update your connection string to use an SQL login, or change your application pool to run under a particular windows login's context which has access to the SQL instance and database.

Comment: You're using **integrated security** in your connection string - that means, the currently logged on user account has to have access to the database. Either change this to explicitly specify a user id and password on your dev web server, or then set up the database that this dev web server talks to to accept that user account as a valid login

Comment: And in the case of a web application on a web server, that "currently logged in user" is the user account that's defined to be running the IIS app pool in which your web application on that server exists - so in this case, it seems, that user account is `Domain\GenericDevLogin`

Comment: Bare with me for a moment.  If I log in to my workstation with a login that has access to the web server and the sql server, and I use integrated security in the connection string, is it failing because once the app is sitting  on the web server, it is no longer running under my logged in credentials?